# Pandas replace function does not work on Series of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pandas.DataFrame.replace doesn't replace string.

```
dic = {'Text': ['i8am going to school', 'i8am a very good boy']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
d = df['Text'].replace(to_replace='i8am', value='i am')
print(d)
```

Expected output:

```
I am going to school
I am a very good boy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with text data, you need to use '.str' more info here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html.

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'Text': ['i8am going to school', 'i8am a very good boy']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
d = df['Text'].str.replace('i8am', 'i am')
```

**Output -**

```
0    i am going to school
1    i am a very good boy
```

Plus, You need to check the function signature. You can't just pass random keyword args and expect it to work.

Comment: you could also add `regex = True` to your initial replace statement.

Comment: @rhug123 the first approach seems good to me.

Answer (score 1):

We can use str accessor and then replace the string over it.

```
d = df.Text.str.replace('i8am', 'I am')
```

**Output**

```
0    I am going to school
1    I am a very good boy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do like `replace`

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace({'i8am':'i am'},regex=True)
```